# Dependence of solar energy absorbed over a year on orientation of solar panel

Tags: solar-cells, intensity

I am trying to find how total solar energy incident, over a year, depends on the orientation of a tilted solar panel. The final goal is to find the optimum direction in which the panel should be pointed and the relative energy loss for deviations from that direction. So far, I have found an equation of incident intensity on a tilted surface given below:
$$ I_{T} = I_\mathrm{DN}\cos{\theta_z}R_{T} + I_\mathrm{d}\frac{1+\cos{\beta}}{2} + I\rho_{g}\frac{1-\cos{\beta}}{2} $$
where $I_\mathrm{DN}\cos{\theta_z} + I_{d} = I$

Here, $\theta_z$ and $R_T$ depend on the time of the year, location on earth and orientation of the surface (panel). $\beta$ is the tilt angle of the surface. These parameters are known to me. But I don't know how to find out the values of $I_\mathrm{DN}$ and $I_\mathrm{d}$ which respectively represent the intensity incident on a horizontal surface when the sun rays are directly normal and the diffuse intensity due to atmospheric scattering. Are these values found out experimentally for any location? Is there a way to find them out without doing any measurement?

I believe integrating this equation over the whole year will give me the total incident energy as a function of the latitude and surface orientation. If there is a better way to do this, please do tell.

Comment: Complete solar calculator: https://pvwatts.nrel.gov/ Very useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cumfy

Comment: The docs on the site go into a lot of detail about the algorithms used iirc. Otherwise nrel has stuff on solar algorithms too.